# mysql-events not executing my code properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, events, mysql-event

I am creating a node app with mysql-events for testing, it works somewhat as expected but my code is not executing properly unless i add `console.log(event);` to the script..?

**This code outputs nothing when I change my database:**

```
var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');

var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: ''
};
var myCon = MySQLEvents(dsn);

var event1 = myCon.add(
  'db.test.name.value',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      console.log("DB change")
    }
  }, 
  'Active'
);

var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: '',
};
var mysqlEventWatcher = MySQLEvents(dsn);
var watcher =mysqlEventWatcher.add(
  'experimental.test',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
     //row inserted 
    if (oldRow === null) {
      console.log("Row inserted");
    }

     //row deleted 
    if (newRow === null) {
      console.log("Row deleted");
    }

     //row updated 
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      console.log("Row updated");
    }

    //detailed event information 
    //console.log(event);
  }, 

);
```

This code outputs the appropiate `console.log`:

```
var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');

var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: ''
};
var myCon = MySQLEvents(dsn);

var event1 = myCon.add(
  'db.test.name.value',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      console.log("DB change")
    }
  }, 
  'Active'
);

var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
var dsn = {
  host:     'localhost',
  user:     'root',
  password: '',
};
var mysqlEventWatcher = MySQLEvents(dsn);
var watcher =mysqlEventWatcher.add(
  'experimental.test',
  function (oldRow, newRow, event) {
     //row inserted 
    if (oldRow === null) {
      console.log("Row inserted");
    }

     //row deleted 
    if (newRow === null) {
      console.log("Row deleted");
    }

     //row updated 
    if (oldRow !== null && newRow !== null) {
      console.log("Row updated");
    }

    //detailed event information 
    console.log(event);
  }, 

);
```

The only difference is at the bottom of the script where in the first code block `console.log(event);` is commented out, but it is not in the second. Why is this?

Comment: what you mean with the code not working properly

Comment: That my console.log: aren't executing unless i add console.log(event);

Comment: does it matter where you add that console.log(event)? I mean, before or after the other console logs?

Comment: No, it does not seem to play any difference.